# Eclipse casting error

Tags: eclipse, selenium, cucumber, eclipse-mars

I recently upgraded from Eclipse Luna to Mars and I am getting the below error while clicking on Maven tab on viewing properties of index.html(Report file of cucumber project).

Please help me with the below error

[image: Screenshot]

It's not stopping me from generating reports but it was not happening before yesterday and I didn't change anything.

Comment: Please include any errors in text format, and look at the log it's telling you to look into

Comment: @JamesZ , no errors as such , i recently upgraded from Eclipse Luna to Mars , i guess the same is causing this issue.